# Dropdown Menu that goes to a URL on submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a WordPress Advanced search that when a user selects the applicable category from the dropdown menu it navigates them to that suggested category. I'd like for it to take them to that category on submit instead of it doing it automatically once the option is selected.
Here is my JS code:

```
$(function(){ // bind change event to select 
    $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () { 
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value 
        if (url) { // require a URL 
            window.location = url; 
        } return false; 
    }); 
}); 

$(function(){ // bind change event to select 
    $('#dynamic_select2').on('change', function () { 
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value 
        if (url) {  // require a URL 
            window.location = url; 
        } return false; 
    }); 
});
```

And Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="treatment-form-procedure">

<label class="selectstyle" id="treatment-procedure-select" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <select id="dynamic_select">
        <option selected>Select One</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/treatment/medical-dermatology/">Medical Dermatology</option>
    </select>
</label>

<input type="submit" value="Search" id="treatmentSubmit" style="padding: 10px 7px;" />
```

Comment: Please format the JS.. or you can except a lot of similar comments..

Comment: @AlexDemchak that's a horrible edit - you actually modified the code, and lost some of it . . .

Comment: Then go fix it `$('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () { var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value` PS - it got approved, so someone else slipped up too.

Comment: @AlexDemchak yeah, actually two reviewers approved it, so plenty of room for blame all around . . . I've got my edit in the queue . . .

Comment: Thank you Ernie, I wasn't aware of how to make it a bit more readable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the javascript handler for the dynamic_select, and the form will no longer submit on change . . . the code you can remove or comment out is:

```
$(function(){ // bind change event to select 
    $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () { 
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value 
        if (url) { // require a URL 
            window.location = url; 
        } return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not very talented with JavaScript. What should I change the JavaScript handler to? Because I still want the url value of the selection to be the place the user is directed to on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the form submit.

```
$('form.treatment-form-procedure').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $('#dynamic_select').val();
});
```

***OR*** (and I like this better) update the form action:

```
$('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', $(this).val());
});
```

... so the form submits to that url.

Comment: Hmm, I tried both of these. On submit it just puts a '?' at the end of url without going anywhere.